# Remove of Specific Customer the table C# SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, database, t-sql

I have a customer cart which is display the cart that customer wants to buy. I want to make a delete row at the customer cart.

The cart display based on the `cust_id`.

I'm using this query to display.

```
SELECT 
    tableCustomerCart.cart_quantity, tableFoodDetail.food_title, 
    tableFoodDetail.food_price, tableFoodDetail.food_image, 
    tableCustomerCart.cart_price 
FROM
    tableFoodDetail 
INNER JOIN 
    tableCustomerCart ON tableFoodDetail.food_id = tableCustomerCart.cart_id 
WHERE 
    tableCustomerCart.cust_id = @cust_id
```

My question is what is the query to delete the specific row for specific id (`cust_id`) ?

[image: This is customer cart display]

[image: this is database tablecustomercart]

[image: this is the sql custom]

This my sql datasource.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM tableCustomerCart WHERE cust_id=@cust_id" SelectCommand="SELECT tableCustomerCart.cart_quantity, tableFoodDetail.food_title, tableFoodDetail.food_price, tableFoodDetail.food_image, tableCustomerCart.cart_price FROM tableFoodDetail INNER JOIN tableCustomerCart ON tableFoodDetail.food_id = tableCustomerCart.cart_id WHERE tableCustomerCart.cust_id = @cust_id">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="cust_id"/>
    </DeleteParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="cust_id" SessionField="cust_id" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="cart_quantity" HeaderText="cart_quantity" SortExpression="cart_quantity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="food_title" HeaderText="food_title" SortExpression="food_title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="food_price" HeaderText="food_price" SortExpression="food_price" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="food_image" HeaderText="food_image" SortExpression="food_image" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="cart_price" HeaderText="cart_price" SortExpression="cart_price" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

'DELETE' Tab.

```
DELETE FROM tableCustomerCart WHERE cust_id=@cust_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the cust_id value is not being set, try adding the DataKeyNames property to your gridview, i.e.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="cust_id" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, your fields, and your schema. Then seemingly you want to delete the cart item. You could probably use a query like this

```
"Delete from FROM tableCustomerCart where cart_id = @cart_id"
```

***Disclaimer***, i cannot be held responsible for the people you maim order otherwise hurt with this code

Comment: I have updated the question, I tried this at the 'DELETE' tab, and it still not working.

Comment: @Zuhrain not working is not a technical description of a problem, you need to tell us what the error message was, most likely you had dependent tables

Comment: There is no error, once I pressed the 'Delete', there is no changes.

Comment: @Zuhrain then it sounds like something is pointing at the wrong database, or this is a benign error which shouldn't happen

Comment: I already checked, there is no errors. Or should I make a new SqlDataSource?

Comment: You should reload data in the view, so deleted record will be removed from the list.

Comment: Can you show what exactly you have configured as Delete command?

Comment: @Zuhrain  - your update shows the select query.  We need to see the delete query (on the Delete tab).